# NSXMLParser get namespace prefix for attribute

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, xml-namespaces

I have an XML structure that looks like:

```
<Succeeded p1:type="Edm.Boolean" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">false</Succeeded>
```

Since I need to be able to get the `p1:type="Edm.Boolean"` attribute and the namespace prefix may be different depending on several forces beyond my control.  I need to figure out how to get the prefix from the namespace URI programmatically.

I have implemented the `parser:didStartMappingPrefix:toURI:` and `parser:didEndMappingPrefix:` delegate methods, and though I have set `setShouldProcessNamespaces` to **YES**, they do not get called.

I am new to NSXMLParser, but not to iOS nor XML.  Any direction on how I should go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to implementing the delegate methods and calling `setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES`, `setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES` should also be called.

This change will cause both "prefix" protocol methods to be called.  There you can capture the namespace URI and prefix and use them as needed.